# How to test window.location in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

In my app that uses backbone I have the following function:

```
  handleModelSaved: function () {
    var redirect_location = 'redirect_path';

    App.Messenger.success('Report was saved successfully!');
    setTimeout(function () {
      window.location = redirect_location;
    }, 2000);
  }
```

For now I have the following test:

```
  describe('handleModelSaved', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      view = initV3View();
      spyOn(App.Messenger, 'success');
      view.handleModelSaved();
    });

    it("sends a success message", function () {
      expect(App.Messenger.success).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Report was saved successfully!');
    });
  });
```

And my question is, how can I test with Jasmine this code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  window.location = redirect_location;
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the location property on the window object to have a specific value. Of course, you can only do this after the timeout has exprired. What you probably want to do is to override the setTimeout function with your own implementation that calls the specified callback function immediately. With that you can also check whether or not the setTimeout was called with the expected timeout. You can do this yourself or use Jasmine's Clock functions to mock the native timeout functions: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

Another option is to use the done function that is passed as an argument to your it() function callback. Which makes the test asynchronous.

Comment: Except that `window.location` will be set to something like `http://localhost:9876/context.html` regardless, no?